# Creation of custom e-mail inbox for each tenant (customer) programatically

Tags: php, email, smtp, office365, multi-tenant

We pair bank transactions via information e-mails. We need to solve: **create own custom domain e-mail inbox** (e-mail account) programatically (PHP), which will serve only for pairing bank transactions. This e-mail will be created for every new tenant (customer). I am not sure if we need own SMTP server or we can buy any outsourcing service (MailGun, Sendgrid ...). Do you have any idea how to solve this please ?
We have own Windows servers and we use Office365 atm, but we are thinking about Microsoft Azure to the future.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You usually don't actually create the mailboxes for each address, you use a host with an smtp that receives every email and forwards it to a program (such as a PHP-script) which processes the received email (usually by putting it in a queue for further processing). There are no actual mail inboxes involved.

Comment: What host do you recommend us for this solution ? I think, that Office365 has licence maybe for Microsoft Exchange or is it something completely different?

Comment: I don't know how to distinguish individual tenant...

Comment: You'd give each tenant an unique (unguessable) identifier in front of the @- i.e. something like `foo-xjKAjskd@forwardhost.domain.com`. You could host the SMTP server on any smaller VM. I'm guessing many email providers will also provide a service that posts each email received to a dedicated webhook endpoint. See https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-receiving.html#how-to-start-receiving-inbound-email for an example.

Comment: Ok I ll try it, thank you.